# How to search a string on google using default browser

Tags: android, android-intent, google-api, android-searchmanager

I want to implement a search function that open the default browser and search the passed string

```
public void searchOnGoogle(String keywords){
---
}
```

Is there a way using intent filter or I must implement everything by myself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode(keywords, "utf-8");
String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" + query;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```